# При компиляции python кода в exe файл с помощи nuitka возникает ошибка

Tags: python, компиляция, nuitka

При вводе команды:

```
   PS C:\Users\Misha\desktop> python -m nuitka --mingw64 NitroSet-gen.py
```

Выходит ошибка и много варнов:

```
Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --mingw64 NitroSet-gen.py
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '0.6.18.2' on Python '3.9' commercial None.
Nuitka-Inclusion:WARNING: Not following import to 'requests' (C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests), please specify --nofollow-imports (do not follow any imports), --follow-imports (follow all generally), --nofollow-import-to=requests (do not follow it), --follow-import-to=requests (follow import it) to change.
Nuitka-Inclusion:WARNING: Not following import to 'PIL' (C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL), please specify --nofollow-imports (do not follow any imports), --follow-imports (follow all generally), --nofollow-import-to=PIL (do not follow it), --follow-import-to=PIL (follow import it) to change.
Nuitka-Inclusion:WARNING: Not following import to 'psutil' (C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\psutil), please specify --nofollow-imports (do not follow any imports), --follow-imports (follow all generally), --nofollow-import-to=psutil (do not follow it), --follow-import-to=psutil (follow import it) to change.
Nuitka-Inclusion:WARNING: Not following import to 'colorama' (C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\colorama), please specify --nofollow-imports (do not follow any imports), --follow-imports (follow all generally), --nofollow-import-to=colorama (do not follow it), --follow-import-to=colorama (follow import it) to change.
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Nuitka\Nuitka\gcc\x86_64\11.2.0-12.0.1-9.0.0-r1\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe (gcc.exe).
FATAL: Error, you seem to be using the unsupported embeddable CPython distribution.
```

Как я могу исправить это?

Comment: И что вам непонятно из того что вам сообщила программа?

Comment: Мне понятно что она говорит, но я спрашивал как это решить.

Comment: Что вы поняли из ошибки?

Comment: Вам говорят что ваша Nuitka не совместима с версией Python. Но такт как у вас Python3.9, а Nuitka его поддерживает,  то смею предположить что разрядность разная. Или же Nuitka фиг знает где скачена и под какую платформу.